# Boxing Shuffle Step in Muay Thai?

Tags: technique, boxing, muay-thai, footwork

Do Muay Thai professional fighters use the Shuffle Step? Bazooka Joe Valtellini is a professional fighter, and teaches both Boxing and Muay Thai. I can' tell if this can be used in Muay Thai, but it definitely can be used in Boxing.

I need to be careful what can be used between two sports, example if you can't bob or weave too low in Muay Thai, due to knees and low kicks.

See video here: It can be used with both left and right hand directions.

There is a certain point where the legs come close together. It may work in boxing, not sure how it works in Muay Thai with being thrown off balance with kicks.

https://youtu.be/7PQUQIFhxSg?t=297

Step images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For traditional Muay Thai, the answer is no. Traditional Muay Thai rule sets favour a block and exchange type approach, not bobbing and weaving or fast shuffling.

As you’ve mentioned, one of the reasons why this puts a fighter at a disadvantage, is the constant movement makes it much more difficult to check kicks, which are high scoring points on the body/head and painful on the legs.

Find some Thai Muay Thai fights on from Channel 7 or Lumpinee stadium for reference and study the style.

This type of move features better in Dutch-style K1 Kickboxing which naturally requires much more movement.

Comment: Welcome to the site SavPhill, This answer is good, but it would be better if you could elaborate on some of the points you make.  Even better if you can provide some evidence but I know that's not always easy.